# Same variable names used in two branches (Git)

Tags: git, coding-style, git-merge

As a social scientist trying to use Git, I have an incredibly newbie question.

Say I have two branches, each contains a variable `foo`. When I merge these two branches, the variable `foo` will be defined in two places, causing confusion.

This is basic coding error in general, not particular to Git of course. But given the extensive practice of branching with Git, people switch context more often and may not remember the variables in existence across all branches.

Is the solution "be more careful" or Git has something to safeguard this?

Comment: It is not something version control specific, but the answer is **tests** (which can be run automatically from *hooks* by version control system, e.g. on commit... well, at least basic fast sanity tests)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that the scope of your variable is as small as possible. 
It's okay to have 2 variables with the same name, if they have their own relatively small scope.
For example, it's perfectly fine to have a `foo` variable in the `Fizz()` method, and have another `foo` variable in the `Buzz()` method, and having this will not result in a conflict on merge.

Should you be in a situation that the same variable name was used in the same scope, you'll have to do a manual merge. The only way of guaranteeing your code is still valid after the merge is to have Unit Tests for each individual code change.
The Unit Tests will also be merged, and should all still validate after the manual merge.